# Class Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler Not working

Tags: magento2.2, session, installation

After fresh installation of 2.2.0 version it gives:

> Class Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface:: ) in     vendor\magento\framework\Session\SaveHandler.php on line 16

Answer (score 2):

Open this file

> vendor\magento\framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface.php

Look for

```
interface SaveHandlerInterface extends \SessionHandlerInterface
```

Replace it with

```
interface SaveHandlerInterface extends \Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface
```